# Running SpringTests / SpringBootTests against standalone / cloud server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

We currently have a setup, where we have lots of tests running as "SpringBootTests". Now, as we develop a cloud application, we want to test the actual scenario and need to run those tests against a cloud deployment of the spring application. I tried various ways like adding server.url or server.host in the config.yml, removing the SpringBootTest application etc., but nothing worked.

Unfortunately, our spring pro is on vacation for some time, yet, so I searched for quite some time on SO and google and didn't find any answer. That's why I ask here, now.

The annotation is like this:
    `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = Core.class)`

config.yml part for the server:

```
server:
  port: 8080
  contextPath: /
```

Basically all I need is to tell the test to not start spring itself, but the use the cloud one, so I need a way to provide port and url to the test.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your input and regards,
Kay

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "I need is to tell the test to not start spring itself, but the use the cloud one"? You want to start your tests on another host?

Comment: I want the tests to not connect to http://localhost:8080/ or but https://my.testhost.net:123/ (example). Tests should run on local machine of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it seems that there was a hardcoded "localhost" deep in the test code (some base test class, which initialises everything). Changing this solved the issue. It seemed to be some spring config issue all the time, so I was quite misled here.